# Як уникнути повтору кореня у виразі "незначне значення"?

Tags: untagged

Візьмемо для прикладу речення з подібним повтором:

> Після повторних замірів точка роси змінилась на *незначне значення*.

Очевидно, звучить воно не дуже гарно. Спроби його перефразувати закінчуюються невдачею:

- "*значення [...] змінилось на незначне (що?)*" — ще гірша тавтологія;
- "*[...] точка роси змінилась на невелике значення*" чи "*[...] на мале значення*" — вислів втрачає виразність і звучить кострубато;
- "*[...] точка роси незначно змінилась*" — корпус [mova.info](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx) має приклади вживання подібних висловів, але з технічного погляду вислів "*точка роси змінилась*" позбавлений сенсу, оскільки змінилось саме її "*значення*", а не точка роси сама по собі;
- "*[...] значення точки роси трохи змінилось*" — в кожній предметній області є розуміння тої кількості зміни, розмір якої описує слово "*незначний*" (або принаймні про це можна домовитись зарання), проте слова "*трохи*", "*невеликий*" тощо явно позбавлені такої властивості (до того ж, виразність явно втрачена);
- "*[...] змінилось на малу кількість*" — одразу з'являється запитання: кількість чого? Проте, навіть якщо уточнити, що мова йде про "*малу кількість сантиметрів / кубометрів / тощо*", звучить це геть паскудно.

Отож, яким чином можна виразно і гарно описати *незначну* зміну певного *значення*? Можливо, якесь із моїх перефразувань насправді широко вживане, і моя претензія до нього є несправедливою?

Comment: "Після повторних замірів значення точки роси змінилось, проте несуттєво" можливо, так?

Comment: Згоден із @Sasha, що слово значення необов'язкове, але якщо все ж треба, то можна спробувати його замінити на *показник*.

Answer (score 3):

Перепрошую, що відповідаю не напряму на Ваше запитання, більшість Ваших претензій мені справді не дуже зрозуміла, тому напишу принаймні те, що я бачу.

Перша моя думка була написати: **«Після повторних замірів точка роси змінилася [неістотно](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=59214&page=1888)»**.

Але мені не дуже подобається твердження, наче точка роси змінилася саме *після замірів*. Так, «після» необов'язково означає «внаслідок», «після» може означати лише порядок у часі, а не причинність, але ж тут нема мови навіть про порядок у часі: точка роси цілком могла змінитися *до* повторних замірів (і найімовірніше так і було), а заміри лише виявили це. Тому б я сказав: *«Повторні виміри/заміри виявили (лише) незначну/неістотну зміну точки роси»* — або ще краще: **«Повторні вимірювання/замірювання виявили (лише) незначну/неістотну зміну точки роси»**​¹.

Позицію «з технічного погляду вислів „точка роси змінилась“ позбавлений сенсу, оскільки змінилось саме її „значення“, а не точка роси сама по собі» я, якщо чесно, не дуже розумію. Тобто змінюється не зріст дитини, а значення зросту дитини, не об'єм газу, а значення об'єму газу? Мені знається це синонімічними формулюваннями. Але якщо я помиляюся і це важливо, то: чи не допоможе, якщо *змінити вислів «точка роси» на вислів «температура точки роси»*? (Або *принаймні на «значення температури точки роси»* — використання слова «неістотний» допоможе уникнути одноманітності «незначну… значення».)

<sub>¹ Багато хто вважає в цьому доречнішим використання слів типу «{ви/за}мір{юва/я}ння», «{ви/за}мір», розрізняючи [дію, подію, наслідок](/a/1311) (див. також [1](http://repo.knmu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/5462/1/%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%87%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%9D%D0%86%20%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%9C%D0%86%D0%9D%D0%98%20%D0%97%20%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%A6%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%9C%D0%98.pdf), [2](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Komisija/Protokol_2002_04.pdf)). Хоча я не вважаю, що в дійсності українська мова настільки «регулярна» й однозначна, але принаймні в деяких контекстах це може бути важливо.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

У початковому реченні у вас теж міняється точка роси, тому `"[...] точка роси незначно змінилась"` є точною заміною. Якщо ж `"[...] точка роси незначно змінилась"` вам не подобається, то і оригінал має не подобатись.

У свою чергу, можу запропонувати такі варіанти

1. ... оцінка точки роси змінилась на незначну величину.
2. ... обчислене значення точки роси незначно змістилось [в плюс або мінус].
3. ... значення точки роси у межах похибки не змінилось [що і означає "незначно" на діалекті науки].